# React typescript echarts - option type error - Types of property 'series' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, echarts

I am using an apache echarts in React for my project. I was using this [article](https://dev.to/manufac/using-apache-echarts-with-react-and-typescript-optimizing-bundle-size-29l8) as a starting point. I have created a codesandbox with an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-sky-frncvy?file=/src/App.js). Codesandox runs with no problem, but when I run it locally on my machine from my project, I get a Typescript error:

> TS2322: Type '{ legend: {}; tooltip: { trigger: string; showContent:
> boolean; }; xAxis: { type: string; }; yAxis: { gridIndex: number; };
> series: { data: number[]; type: string; smooth: boolean; }[]; }' is
> not assignable to type 'EChartsOption'.   Type '{ legend: {}; tooltip:
> { trigger: string; showContent: boolean; }; xAxis: { type: string; };
> yAxis: { gridIndex: number; }; series: { data: number[]; type: string;
> smooth: boolean; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ grid?:
> Arrayable; series?: Arrayable<LineSeriesOption$1>; title?:
> Arrayable; }'.     Types of property 'series' are
> incompatible.       Type '{ data: number[]; type: string; smooth:
> boolean; }[]' is not assignable to type
> 'Arrayable<LineSeriesOption$1>'.         Type '{ data: number[]; type:
> string; smooth: boolean; }[]' is not assignable to type
> 'LineSeriesOption$1[]'.           Type '{ data: number[]; type:
> string; smooth: boolean; }' is not assignable to type
> 'LineSeriesOption$1'.             Type '{ data: number[]; type:
> string; smooth: boolean; }' is not assignable to type
> 'LineSeriesOption'.               Types of property 'type' are
> incompatible.                 Type 'string' is not assignable to type
> '"line"'.  ReactECharts.tsx(31, 5): The expected type comes from
> property 'option' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes
> & ReactEChartsProps'

This is the chart component:

```
import type { LineSeriesOption } from "echarts/charts";
import { LineChart } from "echarts/charts";
import type {
  GridComponentOption,
  TitleComponentOption
} from "echarts/components";
import {
  DataZoomComponent,
  GridComponent,
  LegendComponent,
  TitleComponent,
  ToolboxComponent,
  TooltipComponent
} from "echarts/components";
import type { ComposeOption, ECharts, SetOptionOpts } from "echarts/core";
import { getInstanceByDom, init, use } from "echarts/core";
import { CanvasRenderer } from "echarts/renderers";
import { CSSProperties, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

use([
  LegendComponent,
  LineChart,
  GridComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  TitleComponent,
  ToolboxComponent,
  DataZoomComponent,
  CanvasRenderer
]);

export type EChartsOption = ComposeOption<
  LineSeriesOption | TitleComponentOption | GridComponentOption
>;

export interface ReactEChartsProps {
  option: EChartsOption;
  style?: CSSProperties;
  settings?: SetOptionOpts;
}

export function ReactECharts({
  option,
  style,
  settings
}: ReactEChartsProps): JSX.Element {
  const chartRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let chart: ECharts | undefined;
    if (chartRef.current !== null) {
      chart = init(chartRef.current);
    }

    function resizeChart() {
      chart?.resize();
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeChart);

    return () => {
      chart?.dispose();
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeChart);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartRef.current !== null) {
      const chart = getInstanceByDom(chartRef.current);
      chart?.setOption(option, settings);
    }
  }, [option, settings]);

  return (
    <div ref={chartRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "300px", ...style }} />
  );
}
```

And this is the option prop I am passing it:

```
const option = {
    legend: {},
    tooltip: {
        trigger: "axis",
        showContent: true,
    },
    xAxis: { type: "category" },
    yAxis: { gridIndex: 0 },
    series: [
        {
            data: [45000, 45000, 45000, 45000, 45000, 75000, 45000, 45000, 45000, 45000, 55000, 45000],
            type: "line",
            smooth: true,
        },
    ],
};
```

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "ts-node": {
    // these overrides are used by ts-node
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I am not sure why do I get this error?

Comment: I am using echarts-for-react to render a Pie chart. This is what I am doing and it's working.

```import type { EChartsOption } from 'echarts';
const options: EChartsOption = {...};

<ReactECharts option={options}... />```

See if using EChartsOption type from 'echarts' helps.